# Custom Error when SSL handshake fails

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a SpringBoot REST application deployed on Tomcat 8.I have configured SSL authentication for the APIs exposed.

PFB the configuration in Tomcat.

```
<Connector port="8443" protocol="HTTP/1.1" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" scheme="https" secure="true"
    keystoreFile="D:/sw/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/conf/jks/ServerKeystore.p12" keystorePass="password" keystoreType="PKCS12"
    truststoreFile="D:/sw/apache-tomcat-8.0.23/conf/jks/Keystore.p12" truststorePass="password12" truststoreType="PKCS12"
    clientAuth="true" sslProtocol="TLSv1.2" />
```

I want to throw a custom error message(may be any configuration in tomcat files), when an authorized client with wrong certificates or no certificates tries to hit the server.
Presently iam getting a **http response code 0.**

I have been trying to find out this a lot. Can this be done by any configuration in tomcat.Is this the correct behaviour for SSL authenication failure?

Comment: You shouldn't get 0, you should get 403 or a connection termination. Check your configuration. You don't need a custom error message.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to write your own implementation of the JSSE wrapper class used by Tomcat and configured using the `sslImplementationName` connector attribute.  That wrapper will have to supply your custom version of a socket factory that does the logging you want.  You might be able to get away with a minimal subclass that just does more logging, and just delegates everything to the Tomcat stock JSSE implementation.

Comment: Any pointers or input on custom org.apache.tomcat.util.net.jsse.JSSEImplementation implemntaion that can be used for extra logging?

Answer (score 0):

If the SSL handshake  fails no custom error is possible since there is neither a plain HTTP connection nor a valid HTTPS connection established to send this error. Thus the peer gets at most a TLS alert and will present the builtin error message for such a problem.

Comment: The handshake doesn't fail if the client doesn't present a certificate. It's  optional at the TLS level. It may be mandatory to the HTTP server, but it doesn't get to express that at the TLS level. So the TLS connection does exist, so an HTTP error response is possible. Why the OP is getting zero is another question. He should get 403.

Comment: @EJP: this depends on the server configuration and on the clients behavior. If certificates are required at the TLS level (SSL_VERIFY_FAIL_IF_NO_PEER_CERT) then the handshake will fail if no certificate is sent. If certificates are optional it will not fail if no certificate is sent, but it will still fail if the clients sends a certificate which cannot be verified.  That's at least the case with OpenSSL, but maybe you have more control over this process within Java.

Comment: @EJP: apart from that - the question asked about a custom error message if the handshake fails and that's what my answer is about. If you manage the handshake not too fail that is a different issue.